# How to pair Motorola Barcode Scanner with bluetooth to my mobile device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, barcode-scanner

I bought a LI4278, but I can't figure out how to pair with my Android mobile device.  The barcode scanner didn't come with a manual.

Answer (score 1):

The instruction in the manual are kinda hard to figure out, as what you need to do is located in several places.

[Here is a link to the manual.](http://fleet-maintenance.com/public_downloads/LI4278_Reference_Guide_15183401a.pdf)

First you might need to reset the scanner:

[image]

Then scan the following two:

[image]

[image]

Then enter the pin from your mobile device and you should be good:
[image]
[image]